# Memory leaks using SDL-1.2 , C

Tags: c, gcc, sdl

I'm having some trouble locating the directly and indirectly memory leaks
since they origin in some of the SDL libraries as it seems, could really use some help here. The still reachable memory, as I understood, is some sort of bug in the old SDL, but if there's some magic way to clear it as well I'll be glad to know.

```
==19215== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19215==     in use at exit: 34,164 bytes in 447 blocks
==19215==   total heap usage: 5,994 allocs, 5,547 frees, 4,200,660 bytes allocated
==19215==
==19215== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 102
==19215==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19215==    by 0x6338A0E: _XlcDefaultMapModifiers (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x6338DF5: XSetLocaleModifiers (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x4E75613: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x4E76374: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x4E66C9A: SDL_VideoInit (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x4E40E7B: SDL_InitSubSystem (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x4E40EF3: SDL_Init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x40CB3D: init_sdl (in /specific/a/home/Chess/chess2/Chess)
==19215==    by 0x40CBDC: startGui (in /specific/a/home/Chess/chess2/Chess)
==19215==    by 0x40125A: main (in /specific/a/home/Chess/chess2/Chess)

==19215==

==19215== 12 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 102
==19215==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19215==    by 0x535D679: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==19215==    by 0x6346E56: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x6347C64: _XimSetICValueData (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x6343259: _XimLocalCreateIC (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x6329884: XCreateIC (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x4E7545C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x4E76374: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x4E66C9A: SDL_VideoInit (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x4E40E7B: SDL_InitSubSystem (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x4E40EF3: SDL_Init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x40CB3D: init_sdl (in /specific/a/home/Chess/chess2/Chess)

==19215==
==19215== 192 (16 direct, 176 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 85 of 102
==19215==    at 0x4C2CE8E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19215==    by 0x632F0FD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x632F657: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x6330F04: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x63316BB: _XlcCreateLC (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x634DC9F: _XlcDefaultLoader (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x6338C4D: _XOpenLC (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x6338D97: _XlcCurrentLC (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x6338DCD: XSetLocaleModifiers (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x4E755C3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x4E76374: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x4E66C9A: SDL_VideoInit (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)

==19215==
==19215== 192 (16 direct, 176 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 86 of 102
==19215==    at 0x4C2CE8E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19215==    by 0x632F0FD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x632F657: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x6330F04: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x63316BB: _XlcCreateLC (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x634DC9F: _XlcDefaultLoader (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x6338C4D: _XOpenLC (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x6338D97: _XlcCurrentLC (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x6338DCD: XSetLocaleModifiers (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==19215==    by 0x4E75613: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x4E76374: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==19215==    by 0x4E66C9A: SDL_VideoInit (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)

==19215==
==19215== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19215==    definitely lost: 45 bytes in 5 blocks
==19215==    indirectly lost: 352 bytes in 8 blocks
==19215==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19215==    still reachable: 33,767 bytes in 434 blocks
==19215==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19215== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==19215== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
```

Comment: The "still reachable" memory is not the one being leaked. As the log states, there's still a pointer to these blocks, and they will probably be freed normally upon termination.

Comment: I'd advise you double-check you're using the SDL API as intended (like using `SDL_Quit()` and friends where appropriate), and if you do so, just don't care about this. Some libraries don't really free all memory for performance reasons (e.g. you will see similar things with `ncurses`) on systems that do the cleanup automatically at exit. This isn't a problem at all for one time allocations.